# Python w/ Stripe: How do I get valid JSON from a charge response?

Tags: python, json, stripe-payments

I have a python wrapper method called `succeed` that looks like the following:

```
def succeed(handler, data):
"""Send the given |data| dict as a JSON response in |handler.response|."""
set_headers(handler)
handler.response.write(json.dumps(data))
```

I am trying to pass the result of a Stripe API call to charge a credit card back to another service using this method. Here is the method call, inside of another class:

```
succeed(self, dict(success=True, charge_id=charge.id, response=charge))
```

When I do so, I get a 'charge is not JSON serializable' error. How can I pass all of the charge ID responses along as JSON with this code? Here is the full response:

```
    TypeError: <Charge charge id=ch_103Tsv2kD9PLZlzDG5ce7TE1 at 0x113003b50> JSON: {
  "amount": 3500, 
  "amount_refunded": 0, 
  "balance_transaction": "xxxxxx", 
  "captured": true, 
  "card": {
    "address_city": null, 
    "address_country": null, 
    "address_line1": null, 
    "address_line1_check": null, 
    "address_line2": null, 
    "address_state": null, 
    "address_zip": null, 
    "address_zip_check": null, 
    "country": "US", 
    "customer": null, 
    "cvc_check": "pass", 
    "exp_month": 5, 
    "exp_year": 2015, 
    "fingerprint": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 
    "last4": "4242", 
    "name": "stackoverflow@example.com", 
    "object": "card", 
    "type": "Visa"
  }, 
  "created": 1392181282, 
  "currency": "usd", 
  "customer": null, 
  "description": "X0G0 FEOMSI NA", 
  "dispute": null, 
  "failure_code": null, 
  "failure_message": null, 
  "invoice": null, 
  "livemode": false, 
  "metadata": {
    "email": "stackoverflow@exmple.com"
  }, 
  "object": "charge", 
  "paid": true, 
  "refunded": false, 
  "refunds": []
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `.to_dict()` method to turn a Stripe charge object into a python dictionary.

Serializing a dict is an exercise left to the reader.

---

As an additional fun point, I highly suggest the `dir` function: It lets you see all the possible attributes and methods.

For example:

```
>>> import stripe
>>> dir(stripe.Charge)
['__class__', '__cmp__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'all', 'capture', 'class_name', 'class_url', 'clear', 'close_dispute', 'construct_from', 'copy', 'create', 'fromkeys', 'get', 'has_key', 'instance_url', 'items', 'iteritems', 'iterkeys', 'itervalues', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'refresh', 'refresh_from', 'refund', 'request', 'retrieve', 'save', 'serialize', 'serialize_metadata', 'setdefault', 'stripe_id', 'to_dict', 'update', 'update_dispute', 'values', 'viewitems', 'viewkeys', 'viewvalues']
>>>
```

From here you can see the `to_dict` method. You can also see the `serialize` method, though it's not clear to me what it does.

[More docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir)

Comment: Actually, in the stripe library version I use, this does a somewhat shallow serialization. I was able to solve the issue via this: json.loads(str(stripe_object)) gives you a real dict with no stripe objects, just pure data.

Comment: I can also confirm that ".to_dict()" did not produce serializable json, but that using the method that @ustun suggested does work.

json.loads(str(stripe_object))

Answer (score 3):

Though its late, the following answer may help someone

As per the stripe team `to_dict` method is deprecated. [See here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/issues/314#issuecomment-301434568)

Since the **Stripe** object is the inheritance of `dict`, we can use them as native data type.

Also calling `str("Stripe Object")` will return JSON representation of the object. [See here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/issues/314#issuecomment-301522784)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [this change](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/pull/541), you can now call

```
stripe.util.convert_to_dict(your_stripe_object)
```

to get a recursively constructed `dict`.